# Merging DataFrames using RDotNet

Tags: c#, r, data-structures, dataframe, r.net

I am using REngine and the RDotnet package in c#.
I have List, each DataFrame contains unknown set of columns names, I need to merge all of these dataframes to 1 which has the union columns set of all the dataframes in the List.

What is the easiest way to to this?
I tried the Union, Join methods but didn't understand how to use it well.
thanks!

Comment: I have tried dataframe1.union(dataframe2) and df1.join(df2) and didn't use it fine I guess. The point is that each dataframe can have different columns name (and may have some in common).

Comment: I am not sure what you want exactly? In a `data.frame` object every column needs to have the same number of rows (the object needs to be rectangular). If all columns in all data frames in your list have distinct names and the same number of rows you can just use `cbind()`. If not, how would you want to merge two columns?
Generally, I would recommend creating a working `R` script first, and in a second step port the code to RDotNet.